# Is there a way to switch "To" and "Cc" fields in Google Groups Collaborative Inbox?

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups, collaboration

I'm currently evaluating the Collaborative Inbox of Google Groups to be used as a group inbox for sales orders. The inbox will be able to receive messages from the public.

I'm unable to find how to reply to the sender by using the To field instead of Cc. By default, the receiver is the group itself and the original poster will only receive a carbon copy of the reply. I don't think this is acceptable, mainly because of the semantics and because some people filter email messages based on the role they are set (to/cc/bcc).

If I make a support request or an order to a company, I don't want a carbon copy, I want to be the receiver.

Is it possible to set the original sender as the receiver of the reply and send a carbon copy to the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fair as I know, it's not possible.

If the above isn't a deal breaker, instead of replying from the Google Groups web user interface, consider to reply from the group members own mailbox. The group members could:

- configure their membership settings to receive one email for each new message.
- set their mailboxes reply-to settings to point to the collaborative inbox email address.

**References**
[My membership settings - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1047839?hl=en)